# MongoDB aggregate - join ($lookup) single doc with some highest value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running some aggregate command with $lookup and want to select only a single doc from the lookup result based on some value.

Example:

```
// Add some users
db.users.insert([
  {_id: "1", name: "john"},
  {_id: "2", name: "jack"},
  {_id: "3", name: "jenny"}
])

// Users have projects (owner field refers to user _id)
db.projects.insert([
  // Johns projects
  {owner: "1", name: "john1", lastUpdate: ISODate("2018-01-01T11:00:00")},
  {owner: "1", name: "john2", lastUpdate: ISODate("2018-01-01T12:00:00")},
  // Jennys projects
  {owner: "3", name: "jenny1", lastUpdate: ISODate("2018-01-01T11:00:00")},
  {owner: "3", name: "jenny2", lastUpdate: ISODate("2018-01-01T13:00:00")},
  {owner: "3", name: "jenny3", lastUpdate: ISODate("2018-01-01T12:00:00")}
])
```

Now I want to run some aggregate on `users` and add the project with the latest `lastUpdate` value.
I found 2 ways of doing it and wonder how can I know which is better (performance wise), and whether there is a 3rd more simple and/or efficient.

(Note: the goal of the aggregate query is not just to fetch the latest project, it is just one step in a more complicated query)
(Note2: MongoDB 3.6)

Thanks!

#### First option

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {from: 'projects', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'owner', as: 'projects'}},
  {$addFields: {
    latest_project: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {
          $filter: {
            input: '$projects',
            as: 'proj',
            cond: { $eq: [ '$$proj.lastUpdate', { $max: '$projects.lastUpdate' } ] }
          }
        }, 0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

#### Second option

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'projects',
    let: {uid: '$_id'},
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$owner", "$$uid" ]}}},
      {$sort: {lastUpdate: -1}},
      {$limit: 1}
    ],
    as: 'projects'
  }},
  {$addFields: {project: {$arrayElemAt: ['$projects', 0]}}}
])
```

Comment: Off course the second approach is better which filters the data within the pipeline instead of the second one which first finds all the matched data and then uses `$filter` to remove the unmatched ones.

Comment: I'm completely with @AnthonyWinzlet here. Just make sure you add an index on `owner` and `lastUpdate`.